# Install a windows service from Windows Store application

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-services, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I'm building a desktop application in WPF that installs a Windows Service (that I'm also building) on first start.

I'd like to be able to build and distribute a windows store application out of this.
Building the package seems to work, but when the application tries to install the service, it fails because such an operation needs elevated privileges.

I know that windows store applications run in isolated environment but I really hope that for desktop application (not UWP) there's a way to tweak the appxmanifest to grant such operation.

Any help/advice is welcome !

Comment: Once it's distributed in the store, the technology (wpf/uwp) used is irrelevant. I don't think it's possible.

Comment: It is not possible to install a Windows Service from the store. This might be the closest you can get though https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/create-and-register-a-background-task

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I guess I have to pick a different distribution solution or find a way to get rid of that service (may be _out of process background task_). Maybe there's a way to build a windows store application packaging but distributing it outside the windows store and then get more freedom in the execution environment?

Comment: You can side load windows store apps but maybe steam or some such is more appropriate.